# Google Maps SDK iOS Easy way of getting Capital Cities with Longitude and Latitude

Tags: ios, objective-c, latitude-longitude, google-maps-sdk-ios

Is there an easy way to get a list of Capital Cites with their latitudes and longitudes?

I am just displaying a google map view and I would like to display markers for capital cities.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use google location api service, it is free up to 2,500 url calls per day, [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/#geocoding) is the link for further information.

And all capital cities latitudes and longitudes are listed in [this](http://www.lab.lmnixon.org/4th/worldcapitals.html) website:

**Edited:**
You could use plist directly from [this](https://github.com/daveverwer/Megacities/blob/master/Resources/Cities.plist) website:

[How to parse dictionary object](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Collections/Articles/Dictionaries.html).

Comment: I could geocode them all on the app start but wouldn't it get blocked as it would be lots of requests fast?

Comment: check my edited version. You could use plist directly with no Internet connection

Comment: Thats great. Although I haven't really got any idea how to use it! Im still rather new to iOS, any links?

Comment: I have also added another link for you to learn how to parse/read dictionary object.